# What does **central** mean in the context of probabilistic inference?

Tags: distributions

Page 2 of [this book](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/Joint_MLE_MAP.pdf) says

> The joint probability distribution is **central** to probabilistic inference, because
>   once we know the joint distribution we can answer every possible probabilistic
>   question that can be asked about these variables. We can calculate conditional or
>   joint probabilities over any subset of the variables, given their joint distribution.
>   This is accomplished by operating on the probabilities for the relevant rows in the
>   table.

What does **central** mean here?

Comment: It seems to be the standard meaning of "central" that you would find in any dictionary. Is there a particular concern that you have which makes you think that the common definition of "central" appearing in a dictionary is not the usage intended here?

Comment: Nothing to do with a “central” moment or being in the center of a group. Perhaps “critical” would have been a better word (not really a synonym), but even that has a technical meaning in statistics!

Comment: It means **important**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sycorax suggests in comments, it's one of the standard meanings of the word *central*

> main or important part of something

-- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/central

> of primary importance

-- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/central